# Modify AndroidManifest with Sencha Mobile Packager

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I'm working on a Mobile App using Sencha Touch 2, and I'm using Sencha Cmd 3.1 to generate de APK file.

But seems like it have some kind of Bug that shows the Android Native title bar on the App. I want to hide it because I'm using a Sencha Component for the Title Bar...

On [Sencha 2.1 news](http://www.sencha.com/blog/whats-new-in-sencha-touch-21/) they said this:

> "The packager config also lets you pass in "raw" data to the iOS
>   info.plist and Android AndroidManifest.xml through the rawConfig key.
>   We also heard your feedback about non-admin access to the native
>   packager, and we have updated the setup so admin access is no longer
>   required."

But when I go to [Sencha Official Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/native_packaging) they say this rawConfig key is only for iOS.

It's frustrating! the only solution that I found is to modify the Base AndroidManifest.xml and Add this code... `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar".`

But I would like to do it the good way.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you even access the `AndroidManifest.xml` file? ST deletes the generated files and packages into an APK.

Comment: I had to modify the base AndroidManifest located on {Sencha CMD Path}\stbuild\st-res\android

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Sencha Cmd 3.1, but if you upgrade to version 4.0.4.84 the solution is quite easy.
If you are using Sencha along with "Phonegap", all you are required to do is delve with config.xml. You can use this file to define various configurations for different platforms.

Find the documentation here:
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics